# Comparing two arrays and get the sum of all key=>value where key is in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the array `array1`

```
   array:5 [
  0 => array:1 [
    2 => array:2 [
      "type" => 1
      "score" => 10
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    2 => array:2 [
      "type" => 2
      "score" => 5
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:1 [
    2 => array:2 [
      "type" => 3
      "score" => 4
    ]
  ]
  3 => array:1 [
    2 => array:2 [
      "type" => 4
      "score" => 60
    ]
  ]
  4 => array:1 [
    1 => array:2 [
      "type" => 1
      "score" => 5
    ]
  ]
]
```

I have the second `array2` which is one dimensional

```
array:2 [  0 => 2, 1 => 1]
```

I want to get the sum of all the score values in `array1` where the `array1.key` = `array2.val` which will result to:

```
array:5 [
  0 => array:1 [
    2 => array:2 [
      "score" => 79
    ]
  1 => array:2 [
    1 => array:2 [
      "score" => 5
     ]
    ]
]
```

This is what i've tried

```
// getResult (result,remarks,psychomotor) based on periodid
    $result = Result::join('subject__class_groups', 'results.subjectid', 'subject__class_groups.id')
    ->join('term__session__years', 'results.academic_periodid', 'term__session__years.id')
    ->join('result_types', 'results.restult_typeid', 'result_types.id')
    ->join('terms', 'term__session__years.termid', 'terms.id')
    ->join('academic_sessions', 'term__session__years.sessionid', 'academic_sessions.id')
    ->join('academic_years', 'term__session__years.yearid', 'academic_years.id')
    ->join('subjects', 'subject__class_groups.subjectid', 'subjects.id')
    ->join('class_groups', 'subject__class_groups.classgroupid', 'class_groups.id')
    ->where('results.studentid', $studentid)
    ->where('results.academic_periodid', $periodid)->get();

    $allSubjects = [2,1];
    $subs = [];
    foreach($result as $res){
        // solve for everysubjectid
        $subject = array_push($allSubjects, $res->subjectid);
        $returnValue = array_unique($allSubjects);

            $getScores = array_push($subs, [$res->subjectid=>[
                    'type'=>$res->restult_typeid,
                    'score'=>$res->score_obtained,
            ]]);


    }
    $check = array_intersect_key($returnValue, $subs);

        dd($check);
```

I'm stuck here cos i don't know what exactly to do

so i'll appreciate a bit of help guys... compliments of the seasons
thank you in anticipation

Comment: Ok. So, what have you tried? Where are you stuck? We'll help you with an actual problem, but this isn't a free write-my-code service. See [ask]

Comment: @ADyson i've edited the question and added what i've done

Comment: `array1` is a 2-dimensional array. Which dimension's keys should you compare with the values in `array2`?

Comment: You have duplicate keys `2` in `array1[0]`.

Comment: the first keys are indexes, i want to compare it with the keys  2 and 1 @Barma

Comment: You have duplicate key 2 in array1 [0] as @Barmar wrote. This is not possible in PHP. Please change your example array so that it is a valid array and is written as PHP code.

Comment: @jspit that was an error from me, i've modified it and it's okay now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach( $array1 as $array1x ){
    $key=key($array1x);
    if( in_array($key, $array2) ){
        $this_score = $array1x[$key]['score'];
        $cum_score = isset($newarray[$key]['score']) ? $newarray[$key]['score'] : 0;
        $newarray[$key]['score'] = $cum_score + $this_score;
    }
}
print_r($newarray);
```

DEMO: https://3v4l.org/iKU8j